# Given an nested Array of winning conditions which are indexes compare another fixed length array and return true if given symbol matches those index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 let testArray = Array(9).fill("") 
 
  const winConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  let xValue = "X";
  let oValue = "O";
```

The testArray gets populated with "X" and "O" on button click one at a time. So the end result should be for eg. if "X" is there on testArray index 0, 1, 2 return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function checkWin(value, array) {
    return winConditions.some((cond) =>
        cond.every((index) => array[index] == value));
}

console.log(checkWin(xValue, testArray));
console.log(checkWin(oValue, testArray));
```

`some` returns true if any of the values is true,
`every` returns true if all of the values is true.

Therefore we check on each conditions if the value matches the all of the array values, and return true if any of these conditions is met.

Comment: Is there any chance of getting the true array from winConditions array ?                             ` return winConditions.some((cond) => cond.every((index) => array[index] == value)); ` For eg. getting the "cond" that became true

Comment: You could try to use `find()` instead of `some()`, I think the rest should be the same.
Check this for more info on find: [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Yes, find() gives back the "cond", thanks for the reply.